# Get count File selected Dropzone on another function

Tags: javascript, php, dropzone.js

I have dropzone and button, the dropzone i get limit 8 file, and my problem is i need check if my file is equal same as limit file, not less or not mroe than limit when i press button.
Example :

```
if file<8 || file >8 then Alert ("File must 8!!!") else Do something
```

Can anyone help me???

Sorry my worst grammar :(